# Unexpected behaviour in javascript async function with nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I am creating a script to join multiple databases together.
It must check many variables like primary keys, data types etc..

I have an async function `main` that first of all gets the databases listed in postgresql, it then iterates over them (one-by-one is the intended behaviour) and create a pool.

For each db, it iterates over all the tables, then i populate an array of columns data-types for each table, and then iterate over each record and do my stuff.

The problem is the follow:
From my tests, this loop `for (const table of tables.rows)` does not wait its content before continuing,
so i am having some strange results (i.e. logging table name prints out 5 times before printing the columns  array)

Should i use something like Promises or is there another solution to this problem?

```
async function main() {
    let databases = await getDatabases();

    // Iterates over each database
    for (const database of databases.rows) {
        const slave = new Pool({
            host: "localhost",
        user: "postgres",
        password: "postgres",
        port: 5432,
        database: dbname,
    });

        let tables = await getTables(slave);

        // Iterates over each table
        for (const table of tables.rows) {
            const tableName = table.tablename;
            let columnsData = await getColumns(slave, tableName);
            let columns = [];
            let insertQuery

            // Iterates over each column meta data
            for (columnData of columnsData.rows) {
        columns.push({
            name: columnData.column_name,
                type: columnData.data_type,
            });
        }


        let rows = await getTableData(slave, tableName);

            // Iterates over each record
        for (row of rows.rows) {
                let values = Object.values(row);
        let keys = Object.keys(row);

                // Iterates over each column of a record
                for (value of values) {
                    ...
                    ...
                }
        }

        await target.query(insertQuery);

        }
    }
}
```

```
async function getDatabases() {
    let databases = await target.query("SELECT datname FROM pg_database;");
    return databases;
}

async function getTables(pool) {
    let tables = await pool.query(
        "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema';"
    );

    return tables;
}

async function getColumns(pool, tablename) {
    let columns = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'${tablename}'`);
    return columns;
}

async function getTableData(pool, tablename) {
    let data = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`);
    return data;
}
```

I tried to split the code in functions and awaiting for them, but it does not work.
I expect the code to execute for each table an insert statement of each row (move the data from a db to another with checks built in)

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit your main function as follow.
if you have **async** function in your loop statement it need to have **await** expression before every iteration

```js
async function main() {
  let databases = await getDatabases();

  // Iterates over each database
  for await (const database of databases.rows) {

    const slave = new Pool({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "postgres",
      password: "postgres",
      port: 5432,
      database: dbname,
    });

    let tables = await getTables(slave);

    // Iterates over each table
    for await (const table of tables.rows) {
      const tableName = table.tablename;
      let columnsData = await getColumns(slave, tableName);
      let columns = [];
      let insertQuery

      // Iterates over each column meta data
      for (columnData of columnsData.rows) {
        columns.push({
          name: columnData.column_name,
          type: columnData.data_type,
        });
      }


      let rows = await getTableData(slave, tableName);

      // Iterates over each record
      for (row of rows.rows) {
        let values = Object.values(row);
        let keys = Object.keys(row);

        // Iterates over each column of a record
        for (value of values) {

        }
      }

      await target.query(insertQuery);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried adding await at every loop and it seemed not to work. I will try more with this method and see.